# VSC debugger python not stopping in breakpoint of class method

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have the following code in python, based on a AWS documentation to consume from a Kinesis stream. However my problem is entirely with VSC, not with anything specific of kinesis.

My code is simple

1. It imports some libraries
2. It defines a class, with an init and some method
3. Outside the class definition, it creates an instance with the `__init__` parameters
4. It calls a method from that instance

I want to enter debug mode in VSC. And specifically I want to enter to the method of the class that is being invoked on step 4. I would expect that when I put a breakpoint in the `instance_object.method()` and hit `Step in` it would enter the class's method lines of code so I can go one by one. But instead, it just terminates as if there was nothing to step in to

Here is my specific code:

```py
    import boto3
    import json
    import time
    import datetime
    from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
    
    class Consume():
        def __init__(self,kinesis_client,stream_name):
              self.kinesis_client=kinesis_client
              self.stream_name=stream_name
              self.details=kinesis_client.describe_stream(StreamName='input_stream')
    
        def consuming(self,max_records):
            try:
                response = self.kinesis_client.get_shard_iterator(
                    StreamName=self.stream_name, ShardId=self.details['Shards'][0]['ShardId'],
                    ShardIteratorType='LATEST')
                shard_iter = response['ShardIterator']
                record_count = 0
                while record_count < max_records:
                    response = self.kinesis_client.get_records(
                        ShardIterator=shard_iter, Limit=10)
                    shard_iter = response['NextShardIterator']
                    records = response['Records']
                    print("Got {} records.".format(len(records)))
                    record_count += len(records)
                    yield records
            except ClientError:
                print("Couldn't get records from stream {}.".format(self.stream_name))
                raise

    kinesis_client=boto3.client('kinesis',
                         aws_access_key_id=<some_hidden_string>,
                         aws_secret_access_key=<some_hidden_string>)
    
    consumer=Consume(kinesis_client,stream_name='input_stream')
    consumer.consuming(5)
```

So, I've set a breakpoint at the last line `consumer.consuming(5)` and when the debugger hit's that, I click step in but it just terminates directly.

What am I doing wrong? Here is a picture showing my breakpoints

[image: Breakpoints VSC debugging]

And this is my launch.json . I am also running this locally on a windows 11 machine in plain VSC on the desktop, no docker container nor anything like that

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: setting a breakpoint on a `try` is useless, set a breakpoint on  line 18,19,20

Comment: Just did it, it didn't work. Anyhow lines 18,19,20 are also inside the try. Is it because code inside try are not able to get processed by the VSC debugger?

Comment: you have a useless breakpoint on line 14, there is no code for that line, what if you remove the `try`

Comment: Is it hitting the breakpoint on line 39? Can you Step Into from there?

Comment: what is the value of `consumer` on line 39

Comment: Yeah it hits the one on 39 and then I click on `Step In` but it just exists, it doesn't enters the method line by line.

What do you mean the value of consumer? If I run it on jupyter the return is an object `<generator object Consume.consuming at 0x000002B400223D60>` which is a Kinesis object

Comment: if you don't call `next` of the generator **NO** code will get executed, so no breakpoint hit, I did  not spot the `yield`

Comment: Oh you are right, when I call the generator then it lets me step in

Comment: Hi Eugenio.Gastelum96, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per rioV8 comment, if the return of a method is a generator, which was in this case due to the usage of `yield`. The invocation of the method itself won't trigger any code that VSC debugger will execute as runtime. Only until the generator is called will then be runtime code that VSC will enter the method line by line to execute the code.

In other words, when I added this lines at the end of the code posted in the question

```
generator_data_fetch=consumer.consume(5)
for i in generator_data_fetch:
   print(i)
```

Then, it will enter the code to debug if a breakpoint is set inside the method, or if a breakpoints is set in `for i in generator_data_fetch` and then we click `Step Into`

In other words, if the return of a method is a generator object, VSC will not enter the method for debugging. Only until the generator is called after calling the method that creates the generator